# Airflow Task is stuck in queued status but Dags are in running status (Airflow 2.0.0 web UI)

Tags: kubernetes, airflow-scheduler, airflow

We are in the process of upgrading Airflow 1.10.14 to 2.0.0. the Local/sequential Executors are working as expected, but when using Kubernetes executor, the task are in queued status in airflow UI.
Webserver and Scheduler are running, and I can see Event status is Succeeded in POD scheduler logs.

Anyone having this issue, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome! This question is a little light on detail. What exactly are you seeing in the Airflow UI? Have you looked at the Kubernetes logs and other instrumentation? What do they say about the tasks that you're expecting to run?

Comment: Thank you @josephkibe, Airflow UI is UP ad running . I can see dag is in running status , but the task are on queued status and not moving. Worker Pods are created and deleted in Kubernetes cluster          Here is the details airflow scheduler logs from POD(last line). I dont see any error . :INFO - Executor reports execution of XXXXX execution_date=2021-04-15 19:00:00+00:00 exited with status None for try_number 1